# mail is not sending to customer through comment box in magento admin panel

Tags: magento

we want to send an email to customer through comment box.

but when we type comment and checked " notify customer by email"

and "submit comment" , those comments are displaying below "comment box".

but they are not sending any email to customer.

I enabled Order Comments from System > Configuration > Sales > Sales Email

image for comment box in amdin panel : http://prntscr.com/76j0ad

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the server supports email functionality. If it doesn't support install SMTP pro extension from [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html).